# How to define peer is endorsing peer or Anchor peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have doubt on creating the peer, where to configure, peer is endoser or Anchor.Lets say, After defining the peer of any-type,Is it possible to update peer type, from endoser to anchor viceversa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only peers with chaincode installed can act as endorser, in order to make a node endorser install the chaincode otherwise it'll be simple verify node.
for Anchor peers you need to provide in channel def.

*example:
peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx --tls --cafile tlsca.example.com-cert.pem*

Comment: thank you, It means, if the endoser peer is crashed or shut down, client cannot query or update the data.

Comment: i have one more query, If i set peer has anchor at the starting, if i install the chaincode on that peer, does the peer will convert from anchor to endorser ?

Answer (score 1):

Fabric provide three types of peer:

endorser , anchor and simple peer(verify).

**endorser peer:** peer on which chaincode is installed is called endorser peer.this peer is used to execute smart contract ad return result to client application. client app select that result which is return same from most endorsers.

**Anchor peer:** this peer is used when peer from one org need to communicate with other org.

**for example:**
org1 need to communicate with org2. now communication will be done between anchor peer of org1 and org2.
As you asked in comment peer can act as anchor or endorser peer at same time. **Example :** you can find it in byfn example. where peer0.org1.example.com is anchor as well as endorser.